# Has anyone faced this error in Mule 4, Anypoint studio 7.3.2 - 'Error executing scaffolder'

Tags: mule4

I am trying to generate flows from api RAML in Anypoint studio 7.3.2 when I am getting an error - 'Error executing scaffolder'. The RAML does not contain any errors and works fine. But it does not help me in generating flows from it. I have to create flows manually as a result. Can someone please help me with this issue?

**Error Snapshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems this happens when **"Generating flows from the RAML"** process can not override the changes in the main file (XML file that contains `APIkit` router component). In my case I deleted the Main XML file (Remember to keep a backup in case) and re-did the process.

This generated all added new components for me. But you will have to add flow reference etc. which you did previously in the main XML file.